# Messagelock token expired when resubmitting message on Azure Service Bus queue

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I have an Azure function that has the following simple code:

```
       public class MyDequeuer
        {
            [FunctionName("SampleMessageExecutor")]
            public static async Task Run(
                    [ServiceBusTrigger("test-queue", AccessRights.Listen, Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")]
                    Message inMessage, string locktoken, ILogger log, ExecutionContext ctx)
            { 
               try {
                  some code..
              } catch(Exception e) {
                await inMessage.DeadLetterAsync(locktoken);
              }
            }
}
```

This works fine. However when I at some point later say maybe 1h later or 24h later go to the deadletter queue and try to repair and resubmit the message from the service bus explorer then I see lots of errors saying that the message locktoken has expired. How are you supposed to deal with a scenario where messages can end up on deadletter and maybe reprocessed hours or days later?

I am using function runtime dotnet core 3.1.

Comment: Can you provide a detailed error description? In my case, Message cannot call DeadLetterAsync (locktoken). So I added a messageReceiver parameter, and I did get a lot of errors when running the function. What I want to ask is, is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xi4zE.png) the case you face now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually about this problem there is an issue in github:[How to intentionally deadletter a message in azure functions v2](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1986).

Firstly there is not `DeadLetterAsync` method for Message class, fro v2 or higher you should use `MessageReceiver` to implement it.

Then is about lock token, cause the service bus trigger function will auto complete the message it will cause exception if you want to  `DeadLetterAsync` by yourself. You need to change the host.json, change the `autoComplete` to flase, you could refer to this [host.json setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-output?tabs=csharp#hostjson-settings).

The below is my code, throw an exception and DeadLetter.

```
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task RunAsync([ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue",Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")]string myQueueItem, MessageReceiver messageReceiver, string lockToken, ILogger log)
        {

                try
                {
                    throw new Exception();
                }
                catch (Exception) { 
                    await messageReceiver.DeadLetterAsync(lockToken);
                    log.LogInformation(myQueueItem+ " is put into deadletter");
                }
        }
```

Here is my host.json.

```
{
  "version": "2.0",

  "extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
      "prefetchCount": 100,
      "messageHandlerOptions": {
        "autoComplete": false,
        "maxConcurrentCalls": 32,
        "maxAutoRenewDuration": "00:55:00"
      },
      "sessionHandlerOptions": {
        "autoComplete": false,
        "messageWaitTimeout": "00:00:30",
        "maxAutoRenewDuration": "00:55:00",
        "maxConcurrentSessions": 16
      }
    }
  }

}
```

[image]