# Service bus trigger failing with error "The session lock has expired on the MessageSession.Accept a new MessageSession" some times

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus

Created a azure service bus trigger function. The below is the intial method

```
public static async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("test", IsSessionsEnabled = true)] Message message, MessageReceiver messageReceiver, Int32 deliveryCount, DateTime enqueuedTimeUtc, long sequenceNumber, ExecutionContext context, ILogger log)
```

and host.json is

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
      "prefetchCount": 0,
      "sessionHandlerOptions": {
        "autoComplete": false,
        "messageWaitTimeout": "00:00:01",
        "maxAutoRenewDuration": "00:05:00",
        "maxConcurrentCalls": 16,
        "maxConcurrentSessions": 2000
      }
    }
  }
}
```

MaxLockDuration configured to 1 minute in queue configuration in azure

Based on the above configuration MaxLockDuration < maxAutoRenewDuration and session is enabled.
Auto renewal should happen automatically based on azure documentation. And LockedUntilUtc property giving 9999-12-31T23:59:59.9999999Z always.

I don't understand what is the reason for the issue. I tried to reproduce the issue using below cases

1. MaxLockDuration > maxAutoRenewDuration and process not completed with in MaxLockDuration and if user try to do await messageReceiver.CompleteAsync(lockToken).
2. MaxLockDuration < maxAutoRenewDuration. Called twice messageReceiver.CompleteAsync(lockToken) at the end. The second call throwing same error.

The above two cases are used to reproduce the issue. But in real time my code not fall into those categories. Still I am getting error when load is more.

Answer (score 0):

> Service bus trigger - "The session lock has expired on the MessageSession.Accept a new MessageSession"

I believe this error might be one of these 2 reasons:

1. For too long time, the lock has been opened. So, Calling ***RenewLockAsync*** helps before the lock expires.
2. After the lock has been released, it cannot be used. If the message lock has been explicitly released, through a call to CompleteAsync, AbandonAsync, DeadLetterAsync, etc that would be indicated as a bug.

And this issue is in *open state* in the GitHub Repo and routed this to the appropriate team for follow-up.

Please check the few workarounds to this kind of error:

**References**:

1. [Seeing Service Bus Lock Exceptions for Session Enabled Service Bus Subscriptions](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/26755)
2. [[BUG]Incorrect error: The session lock has expired on the MessageSession. Accept a new MessageSession](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/19662).
3. [Messagelock token expired when resubmitting message on Azure Service Bus queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60645347/messagelock-token-expired-when-resubmitting-message-on-azure-service-bus-queue)

Comment: Thanks, But setting maxAutoRenewDuration will renew lock automatically based on documentation.  "But instead of the hard work of doing it by hand, you can leverage the auto-renew lock feature by setting MaxAutoRenewDuration property of MessageHandlerOptions." link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63585687/azure-service-bus-how-to-renew-lock

Comment: Yes, there is a workaround for setting `maxAutoRenewDuration` in the 3rd Reference!

Comment: In my configuration set maxAutoRenewDuration to 5 minutes and MaxLockDuration is 1 minute. Mean lock never expiry it should renew automatically. But still facing issue occasionally.

Comment: Hello @laxman, the same issue is in an open state in the GitHub Issues Repo. Please keep track of the updates on the above GitHub References given!